# Snap object to place when hit by collider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I snap an object with a rigidbody when it gets hit by a box collider?
The object needs to be snapped to a position when it enters a collider.

I have tried to make it happen but as soon as the box enters the collider, the object gets thrown away.

Comment: Then you wanted a trigger not a collider perhaps

Comment: It is not clear what you're trying to achieve, or how you tried to achieve it so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, I did it using Box Collider itself. here is the working code, it works now:

```
public class SnapModelToPosition : MonoBehaviour {
    public Rigidbody rb;


    Vector3 newPos =  new Vector3(0.1192573f, -0.630803f, 0.02599394f);
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        rb.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
        if(col.gameObject.name == "SnapToPosition")
        {
            Destroy(rb);
            this.transform.localPosition = newPos;
            this.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, -90.00001f, 0);  
        }
    }
}
```